# Replacing the contents of file1 with the corresponding value found in file2

Tags: shell, unix

I have 2 txt files

file 1

```
vol12     
abc_xyz     
vmfs_unix
vol5
vol4
titan6lr_blr
```

file 2

```
vol12 ,cs_rvl      
vol12 ,cvs_rvl     
vol12 ,svn_rvl     
vol12 ,swarch      
abc_xyz ,abc_xyz 
def6g ,def6g  
vmfs_unix ,vmfs_unix
vol5 ,images
vol4 ,svn_blr
vol4 ,home4
```

I need to replace the vol12, vol5, vol4 of file 1 with the corresponding value found in file 2 column 2 
The output should be :

```
cs_rvl      
cvs_rvl     
svn_rvl     
swarch 
abc_xyz     
vmfs_unix
images
svn_blr
home4
titan6lr_blr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop to read file1 and grep the new values out from file2 as shown below:

```
while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ ^(vol12|vol5|vol4) ]]
    then
        grep "$line" file2 | cut -d, -f2
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < file1
```

Output:

```
cs_rvl
cvs_rvl
svn_rvl
swarch
abc_xyz
vmfs_unix
images
svn_blr
home4
titan6lr_blr
```

Comment: Thanks, but (vol12|vol5|vol4) is just an example... it can be anything so can't use a fixed parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version :

```
#!/bin/bash

 arr=$(grep -v "^$" $1)
 echo -n "" > $1
 for match in ${arr}
 {
    i=$(grep ^$i -c $2)
    if [ $i -eq 0 ]
    then
            echo $match >> $1
    else
            grep ^$match $2 | cut -d "," -f2  >> $1
    fi
}
```

Run the script to get the result in file1 itself as follows :

```
./script.sh file1 file2
```

Brief Explanation : 
Iterate through every nonempty line of file1. Each line will be a word(as per the question). Then have a count for every such word in file2. If count is zero, print the word itself. Otherwise print second columns of all the matches for that word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure awk based solution:

```
awk -F"[, ]+" '$1 ~ /^vol/ && NR==FNR { 
   if ($1 in a)
      a[$1]=a[$1] ORS $2;
   else
      a[$1]=$2;
   next
}
NR>FNR && ($1 in a) {
   print a[$1]
}
NR>FNR && !($1 in a) { 
   print $1
}' file2 file1
```